# GWT/RPC - Does gwt supports generics which uses <?>

Tags: gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc

I just tried to compile my client code and faced this

```
        [ERROR] [com.mycompany.project.App] - In order to produce smaller client-side code, 'Object' is not allowed; please use a more specific type (reached via com.mycompany.project.client.bean.Test<?>)
```

... kind of exception;

the bean I am trying to send to server is something like this

```
public final class Test<A> implements IsSerializable{


    private A a;    


    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a= a;
    }



}
```

As I can see it, the compiler make noise of the `<?>` generics unspecific type :S So I've being thinking how to walk it around or there is still a way to make it work as it is because I am quite interested in *RPC abstraction support*? I dearly need your advice here.

Thanks

P.S. GWT 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with something like `< ? extends MyGenericObject >` ??? Maybe it suits for you...

Comment: Emm... you mean a class which extends something what extends MyGenericObject? Should the MyGenericObject be in project classpath ? Could you show a more detailed code snippet please?

Comment: You are right; I tried the solution... It compiled well; Thanks :)